# How to make the size of fixed `text()` to mach the size of a moving `text()` in R

Tags: r, function, plot

If you run my small function below, you'll see something like the below picture.
The **Smaller-sized** "**Here**" are ***fixed*** all around the curve. But the **Larger-sized "Here"** is ***moving*** if you run my function multiple times (***see my R code further below***).

**My question** is how I can have the size of the fixed "HERE" `text()` to become equal to the size of the Moving `text()` **ONLY WHEN** THE TWO PIECES of TEXT FALL on TOP of EACH OTHER?

**Please see my annotated R code below.**

[image]

```
Here = function(){

curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4)

x.on.curve = seq(-4, 4, len = 21) # x.values for fixed text
y.on.curve = dnorm(x.on.curve)    # y.values for fixed text

xx  <- sample(x = seq(-4, 4, len = 21), size = 1) # x.values for moving text
yy  <- dnorm(xx)                                  # y.values for moving text

text(x.on.curve, y.on.curve, 'Here') ## whenever the x.values of a fixed 'HERE' 
                                      # matches the x.value of the moving 'HERE'  
                                      # in below "text()", change cex = 2, ELSE cex = 1

text(xx, yy, 'Here', cex = 2)         

}

## Please run multiple times here:
Here()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
Here = function(){    
   curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4)
   x.on.curve = seq(-4, 4, len = 21) # x.values for fixed text
   y.on.curve = dnorm(x.on.curve)    # y.values for fixed text

   ind <- sample(1:21,1) # index of the x and y values for moving text

   text(x.on.curve[-ind], y.on.curve[-ind], 'Here')    
   text(x.on.curve[ind], y.on.curve[ind], 'Here', cex = 2)    
}

## Please run multiple times here:
Here()
```